# Raspberry Pi Kiosk mode for displaying live data stream

Tags: python, web-development, web, node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for some reccomendations or feedback on my software stack for a Raspberry Pi project.

I am designing a system to read and display information from a CAN bus and display it on a Raspberry Pi (like a car dashboard), I wish for the system to run on startup and be very stable but also have a responsive and clean UI.

My first idea was to use python and Tkinter to create a program that both reads data from the bus and handled the UI however I have found Tkinter to be painful for developing good looking UI that can be easily modified.

Next, I looked into running a web browser in [Kiosk mode](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-kiosk/). This would be preferable for me as I have much more experience in developing web UIs, with this method I then have a range of choices for software for connecting between the backend handling the CAN bus and UI front end.

My question specifically is there a good software stack for developing stable UIs which can be updated with new data in real-time that preferably have a good looking and easy to develop UI. My first consideration has been either a flask or node-js server which handles reading from the Bus and logging and then sends the data to the webpage using WebSockets, however, I'm unsure if this method will be reliable enough for my application.

Any advice or feedback is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm also not sure as to whether this is the best place to ask this question. If this doesn't fit or there's a better place to post this please let me know.

Comment: "`My question specifically is there a good software stack ...`" - sounds on-topic to me. For configuring whatever we recommend, see our [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) sister site. Good luck :-)